# PHP Count Logged-In Users

Tags: php, user-accounts

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can count the number of logged-in users in my application.

**What I have:** When a user logs in, they get a session (which is used when the user wants to visit a protected page) and the IsLoggedIn column for the user in the users table is set to 1 to indicate that the user is logged in. When the user logs out, the value is set back to 0. Counting the number of 1s in the users table makes it easy to return the number of users logged-in. But...

**The Problem:** If the user closes the browser without logging out, the value in the database stays 1, indicating that the user is still logged in even though their session has ended when they closed the browser.

**Question:** Could some one suggest a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Just wanted to add another possibility is having an ajax request on each page that "phones home" every 30 seconds or so, and the user is marked as still being online. It's a bit more complex though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rather than a IsLoggedIn column, you should add a LastTimeSeen column. Any time a person visits a page you update the column:

```
UPDATE members SET LastTimeSeen = NOW() WHERE id = $the_user_id
```

Then to get how many people are on the site at any given moment you use the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE LastTimeSeen > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

That shows how many people have viewed a page in the past 5 minutes, which is the best you're gonna get without a much more complicated solution.

Comment: Why would you use a where clause like that? He wants to know how many users are logged in. Not if a specific user is logged in.

Comment: Is the update statement per user or the last time a page was accessed?

Comment: *smacks head* Now I see why Rudu said use a where statement. I thought he was talking about the second query. Yes, I

Answer (score 4):

Just to offer another solution:

```
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {
  touch("/writable/path/loggedInUsers/" . $user->id);
}
```

If you don't need to query this data, a local file touch is far faster than a DB write. To get logged in users, scan the directory for filemtimes under N seconds old.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing some tests on that. I suspect updating the db could be faster in many circumstances.

Comment: A 0 byte file touch should take almost no time, even worst case on NFS. Again, this solution trades easy query-ability for speed.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way our site is constructed, it was necessary to use the ajax approach.  I'm using jQuery so it's relatively painless.

These lines went into the $(document).ready function.

```
fnShowImOnline();
setInterval('fnShowImOnline', 120000);
```

This is the javascript function...

```
function fnShowImOnline() {
    $.get('ajax/im_online.php');
}
```

And here is the PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ((isset($_SESSION['user']))&&($_SESSION['authorized']=='authorized')) {
        include('../includes/db.php');
        db_connect();
        mysql_query("UPDATE members SET last_checked_in = NOW() WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user']['user_id']}");
    }

?>
```

The count is straight PHP/mySQL.

```
//  Members online.
$online_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members where last_checked_in > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)";
$online_RS = mysql_query($online_sql);
$online_row = mysql_fetch_row($online_RS);
$online = $online_row[0];
```

For those times I need to update the numbers dynamically, this bit of ajax does the trick.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/members_online.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        if (!isNaN(response.total)) {
            $('#OnlineTotal').html(response.total + " Total ");
            $('#OnlineOnline').html(response.online +  " Online Now");
        }
    }
})
```

using this for the PHP/mySQL

```
//  Members online.
$online_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE last_checked_in > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)";
$online_RS = mysql_query($online_sql);
$online_row = mysql_fetch_row($online_RS);
$online = $online_row[0];
//  Members total.
$total_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members";
$total_RS = mysql_query($total_sql);
$total_row = mysql_fetch_row($total_RS);
$total = $total_row[0];
$response = json_encode(array('total'=>$total,'online'=>$online));
echo($response);
```

This is working well for us.