# How can I use OpenID for Steam to print user's fields on a different database?

Tags: php, mysql, openid, steam

I have the following PHP code:

```
<php>
$servername = "host";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT steamid, bananas FROM es_player";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "PLAYER'S STEAM ID: " . $row["steamid"]. " - PLAYER'S BANANAS: " 
.$row["bananas"]. " <br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

It just fetches specific fields from my database. When user's login, they use OpenID, and it is not through an actual database under my control. It is through Steam, users login with their Steam account through OpenID. I am able to fetch the user's SteamID with this when they log in, and there is even a variable for it.

I need to use this SteamID variable when they are logged in to specify which row they are on the database, and print ONLY the logged in user's profile fields, rather than just printing all rows in the database. This will be done using the SteamID of the user that logs in which will be compared against the SteamID field on my database, so that it will know which user you are when you log in.

I do not know how to accomplish this, which is why I am posting here. I just need the PHP code, or some help writing it.

Comment: There's really no need [to delete and repost](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28912966/472495) your question, especially since it removes the comment history. I asked if you could be more specific about where you are stuck - "all of it" makes this, I think, too broad for Stack Overflow. If you can suggest one _particular_ thing that you would like help on, that would be most helpful for readers.

Comment: How are you reading a user's Steam ID? If you don't have any code for that, that is what you need to start on. I use [lusitanian/oauth](https://packagist.org/packages/lusitanian/oauth) on GitHub to set up an app as an OpenID consumer, seems to work fine.

Comment: [See code examples here](https://github.com/halfer/awooga-app/tree/master/src/Core/Auth). It isn't trivial, unfortunately, for the beginner programmer. If you find the above a bit complicated, maybe search for "Steam OpenID PHP" - maybe there is some code you can use directly?

Comment: Hang on, [the library](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication) you mentioned in your original question may do just fine. Have you looked at the supplied demo?

Comment: Well, my problem is that I am using this: https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication but it does not give me their actual Steam Profile ID, it gives me their Steam Community ID (AKA Steam ID 64. I am not sure how to get the actual profile ID, which is what I have saved in my player database.

Comment: And my second problem is that I do not know how to print ONLY the fields of the logged in user from my database, even if I can fetch their SteamID instead of their SteamID64. That was my main reason for posting here, so somebody could possibly provide me with a method by which I can take the SteamID of the logged in user and compare it to the SteamIDs on my player database so that it will know which user is logged in and I can print their profile fields from MY database. Currently  I have a script that fetches ALL of the profile fields that I need found here: http://centaurilegion.net/test.php

Comment: I don't know what a Steam ID is, nor a community ID, so I don't independently know that one can necessarily be derived from the other. Are you sure they are linked? If you don't know this is possible, perhaps you can store their profile ID instead of their community ID instead, so that the problem resolves itself?

Comment: Your second question, on how to list only logged-in users, can be done with a database - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002159/php-count-logged-in-users). Update a `last_seen_at` field when a user does something, and when you show this page, show the users who have been seen in the last 10 minutes.

Comment: Sir, I have a database. When a player joins my server, a profile is created for them on the database. When players login through the site, they use Steam. I do not have access to Steam's databases, therefore I cannot control anything about their info while logged in. However, my database saves their Steam ID when they join the server, and obviously so does Steam. I just need a way to make it so that my database will know which user is logged in by comparing the logged in user's SteamID to all profile rows in my database, which will then allow me to print specific fields from their profile ....

Comment: (CONTINUED) ... on my database, such as the amount of points they have on our servers, etc. If there is a PHP developer on here who wants to work with my to develop a complex system, I am willing to pay anyone to help me, though I'd prefer the nice community of Stackoverflow to assist me for free. All help is much appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: I don't want to display only logged in users, I want ONLY the user that is logged in to see THEIR profile fields. (only specific profile fields set by me)

Comment: "I want _only_ the user that is logged in to see _their_ profile fields" - ah right, sounds like you need sessions. See php.net/session for more, or search here.

Comment: As for the other problem, I previously asked "Are you sure they [Steam IDs and community IDs] are linked?" - **please answer that question**.

Comment: Yes sir. The Steam Communtiy ID is the 64 bit version of the SteamID (32 bit) and it can be mathematically translated.

Comment: Do you know how to do that mathematical translation? That seems to be the key issue here. When the user creates an account on to your system, you can do the translation and then store both profile types.

Comment: I'll get that translation later. I just need the PHP script, that is my main reason for coming here, to help me with the PHP.

Comment: If the code to do the translation is not generally available, you have to write it yourself.

Comment: Let's pretend I already have the Steam ID problem solved. How do I use it as a variable for logged in users to compare it against the Steam IDs of users stored in my own database so that when they log in through my Steam OpenID, the script will know which user they are in the database so I can print their profile fields from my database where I please. I am already able to print their steam profile fields when they log in through OpenID, so that isn't the issue. I need to do exactly as I said, figure out which row they are in my database table by simply using the SteamID of the user logged in.

Comment: I'll handle the mathematical equation part on my own, unless somebody here knows how I can convert a 64 bit Steam ID into a 32 bit one. I DO know a function that can do this, but I have no idea how to do it. I will post it here shortly and see if you guys have any idea what to do with it. Again, thank you for helping.

Comment: I believe that the function that I am going to post is for translating the 32 bit steam IDs into 64 bit ones. The 32 bit are the ones on my database, while the 64 bit are the ones that OpenID is giving me when they log in through steam.

Comment: I'm doing this because I'm in charge of a large community with over 600 users, so this is of much importance to me.

Comment: Here is the link to the function:https://gist.github.com/almirsarajcic/4664387 ... I think you can use that for 32 to 64 bit and vice versa, so it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

You have several related problems that need more research. Since I've voted to close the question as too broad, I will mark this answer as Community Wiki. I really want to help, but in common with the values of the community here, I would encourage you to take the following points and to use them as avenues for further search-engine research. Your post for "just [needing] the PHP code" is a request for free work, which we try to discourage here.

I *think* I understand the problem, but I have no experience of the Steam API, so you may need to read their docs and adapt the following. If you have not used APIs or sessions before, hiring a freelancer in your locality may be the quickest and easiest route to getting your project on the road. You may only need a few hours of their time, so it need not be expensive.

1. Your OpenID script should deliver to your application one of the profile IDs you've described. When a user first creates an account in your site, you need to capture that profile ID and store it against other information of interest. At this point you should run the conversion routine, so that you have the other profile ID, and you can then store that too.
2. When the user logs on, you need to create a session. This is usually as simple as using `session_start()` and then saving the user record primary key as a variable, thus:

   ```
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userId;
   ```

   The user ID will come from your login screen, where you get an OpenID callback to prove that the current user does indeed own the Steam profile ID they have supplied to you. Having a session set up means that any subsequent page browsed by the user will have their user ID available, until they log off. This means that you don't need to do an OpenID call on every page.
3. Using this session ID, you can now obtain either of profile IDs you require, since they are both in your database. This is a trivial `SELECT` database operation involving the session ID, which you can read from `$_SESSION['user_id]`.

Here is an example of a table in an [OAuth application I wrote](https://github.com/halfer/awooga-app) (it's open source, so you can pull it apart if you like). When the user logs on, this record is either created (if it does not exist) or updated (if it does exist):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user_auth;
+----+---------+---------------------------+----------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | username                  | provider | last_login_at       |
+----+---------+---------------------------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | https://github.com/halfer | github   | 2015-01-13 18:05:49 |
+----+---------+---------------------------+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `username` is the OpenID identifier, the `provider` is useful if you allow the user to choose from several authorisation systems (Steam being another), and of course the `last_login_at` is self-explanatory.

---

I also advised in the comments that you may have to write this code. Library re-use is a commendable habit to get into, but unfortunately there is not a library for every eventuality - sometimes the programmer just has to write something him or herself. We frequently see requests on Stack Overflow for a "library/tutorial/step-by-step guide for [project X]" here, and if readers can persuade posters that programming isn't really like that, they will have passed on a very useful lesson.

So, try the above in order? Feel free to ask for further help if I have misunderstood some basic part of the structure, but otherwise, please do use the keywords I've mentioned and pop them in a search engine. It's the only way to learn. Good luck!

Comment: Your info is very useful, thank you for helping a lot. I think you misunderstood one key factor. You said "when a user first creates an account with your site." They do not create an account, they login with steam, I do not store anything when they log in. Should I? It does, however, create a session. I already have it running. I can design the entire website perfectly right now, minus the fact that I'll be missing the feature where it displays specific fields from my database that I'd like to display for them when they log in. Since I can't accomplish this on my own.... (read next comment)...

Comment: I suppose I'll have to just hire somebody to help me. Would you be able to point me in the right direction, or perhaps give me a bit more specific help yourself? I have never written anything large in PHP, I don't know much of what I am doing, but I do have a seemingly adept understanding of the concept, I just do not know the language all too well, nor do I know the Steam API. Sorry for posting such a broad question. So back to my previous question, do you think you can point me in the right direction to find a PHP freelancer to help me write this?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helps. _"They do not create an account, they login with steam, I do not store anything when they log in. Should I?"_ - see my answer update. I understand that they log in with Steam, but I think you should indeed create/update a record when they do so. This will allow you to block users if you wish (it's a good facility to have even if you don't immediately need it) and you can keep a record of their last login time as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any experience of hiring freelancers, so I don't know where to recommend. I tend to think that people are best hiring in the same country as themselves, so that they can use the telephone, and so there are less opportunities for cross-cultural misunderstanding. Maybe a search for "PHP freelancer Iceland" (or wherever you are based). A PHP freelancer in the UK (where I am) will cost GBP200-400 per day, but you can get a day from a programmer in India for (guessing here) GBP80. Of course either can be good or bad, so try to get references if you can.

Comment: Also, in relation to the login record, this will make your profile ID conversion easy. You _could_ just store the Steam ID in the session and convert it on-the-fly, but I prefer using the database record - it feels like it is more flexible.

Comment: Alright, this should explain the conversion http://www.martinpace.com/downloads/SteamIDtoCommunityID.pdf ..... and this should help with the database setup I wanted to write: SELECT * FROM db WHERE id = $id ....
does any of this help you formulate a better explanation of how I can get this done now? Thank you so much for helping me as much as you have!

Answer (score 0):

It was actually quite simple. First, I took the SteamID 64 variable $steamid and ran it through this conversion, which will output the SteamID 32

```
$id = $steamid;

function parseInt($string) {
    if(preg_match('/(\d+)/', $string, $array)) {
        return $array[1];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }}

$steamY = parseInt($id);
$steamY = $steamY - 76561197960265728;
$steamX = 0;

if ($steamY%2 == 1){
$steamX = 1;
} else {
$steamX = 0;
}

$steamY = (($steamY - $steamX) / 2);
```

And then to finish it off, I just made a variable that combined it into the full STEAM_0:000000000 combination.

```
$steamID = "STEAM_0:" . (string)$steamX . ":" . (string)$steamY;
```

I can now use $steamID as a variable on any page that I include this code on. I answered this myself so that if anybody else has troubles with this like I originally did, the answer will be here for them :)