# Count total login users with help of Session in php

Tags: php, database, session

A beginner here.

I want to count total number of logged-in users from a database.

In my code as soon as a users logs in, his user_id is stored in session with index "id".

```
$_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
```

Now I have seen questions like total active session count but non is counting session for a specific session index.

My question is how to count all active `$_SESSION["id"]` ?

Comment: I feel that this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002159/php-count-logged-in-users is probably a duplicate of this question.

Comment: You can also post your own answer below and include the codes from that link http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/register-login-script-users-online_s2 you found. Stack lets you do that ;-)

Comment: you're welcome Darshan