# Need to see how many active sessions I have by user type

Tags: php, session

After several years of retirement from PHP development (10+  years), I am resurrecting my very rusty skills and I am trying to get what should be a simple application working.

I have 2 types of users- "A" and "B". The user types are recorded in the data base. I need to see how many of each type of user is online at any particular time (sessions). I would like instant results, but a lag time of a minute or so is acceptable for this application. I am using PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5.5.52.

It would be GREATLY appreciated if answers were as simple and gave as much complete code as possible. I have researched this question on this site, but could not find an answer that worked for me.

Comment: If you are returning to PHP after 10 years, start by trying www.php.net , it has documentation for all the functions available in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Count Logged-In Users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002159/php-count-logged-in-users)